# How to access docker daemon with in AWS Lambda function?

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda

I wanted to load a docker image from s3 and push it to ECR from my lambda. Below is my code

```
ecr_client = boto3.client('ecr')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
docker_client = docker.from_env()


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    logger.info("the event {}".format(event))
    file_location = event["filelocation"]  # artifact table
    binary_name = event["binary_name"]
    drop_number = event["drop_number"]
    bucket = event["bucket"]
    org_user = file_location.split('/')[0]
    try:
        ecr_client.describe_repositories(repositoryNames=['beta' + org_user + '/' + binary_name])
    except ecr_client.exceptions.RepositoryNotFoundException:
        # create ECR repository
        ecr_client.create_repository(
            repositoryName='beta' + org_user + '/' + binary_name)
    ecr_repository_uri = ecr_client.describe_repositories(repositoryNames=['beta' + org_user + '/' + binary_name])["repositories"][0]["repositoryUri"]

    logger.info("ECR Repository uri... {}".format(ecr_repository_uri))

    # download from s3
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)
    downloadpath = file_location.split('/')[-1]
    with open(downloadpath, 'wb') as data:
        bucket.download_fileobj(file_location, data)
    logger.info("Image successfully downloaded  from s3 ....")


    with open(downloadpath, 'rb') as file: docker_client.images.load(file) #upload image to docker
    docker_client.images.get("eco-spec-docker").tag(repository=ecr_repository_uri, tag = drop_number)#tag load image
    for line in docker_client.images.push(repository=ecr_repository_uri, tag=drop_number,  stream=True, decode=True): # push image layers top ECR
        logger.info(line)
    logger.info("Image Pushed to ECR ....")
    #remove image
    os.remove(downloadpath)
    logger.info("Removed image file ..")
    logger.info("Process successfully ended")

    
    

event = {
    "bucket": "gehc-us-west-2-519101792343-test-eai-sftp-utyfbvsj",
    "filelocation": "lf-capella-orga/eco-spec-docker.tar",
    "drop_number": "123",
    "binary_name": "dummy"
}
```

But since lambda itself doesn't have docker daemon installed in its environment i am getting below error

[ERROR] DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

Is there any workaround I can do here with lambda to do the docker load and docker push.